# how do i create object variable out of the type Product?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created class named product, how can I create object variable of type product?
This class I created for a store to keep a track on the product data.

```
 class Product:                              
   """Class for representing product"""
   def __init__(self, ProdName, ProdNumber, ProdPrice, InvCount):
      self.Name = ProdName
      self.Number = ProdNumber
      self.Price = ProdPrice
      self.Inven = InvCount
      self.__PropTax = 0.20
```

Comment: You mean you want to instantiate `Product`? If so, it's just `my_product = Product(a, b, c, d)`.

Comment: Just use the class name like a function call, which will invoke the constructor `__init__` and return a new object of type `Product`, like so:  `my_prod = Product(name, num, price, count)`

Comment: @TomKarzes - thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple in python.

```
In [1]:  class Product:                              
   ...:        """Class for representing product"""
   ...:        def __init__(self, ProdName, ProdNumber, ProdPrice, InvCount):
   ...:               self.Name = ProdName
   ...:               self.Number = ProdNumber
   ...:               self.Price = ProdPrice
   ...:               self.Inven = InvCount
   ...:               self.__PropTax = 0.20
   ...:         

In [2]: P = Product("name", "PROD123", 1.0, 10)

In [3]: P.Name
Out[3]: 'name'

In [4]: P.Number
Out[4]: 'PROD123'

In [5]: P.Price
Out[5]: 1.0

In [6]: P.Inven
Out[6]: 10
```

If you have any doubts how this works, let me know.

Also, I would suggest you to go through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332454/

Comment: why have you used [5][6], what does the racket and the number enclosed represent?

Comment: why have you written In and Out like one below the other, will I have to code it individually to form a better code like you did? Apologies for so many question, I am new to python.

Comment: Yes.  "In[1]: statement"  stands for the statement which was being executed. "Out[1] Output" shows the output of statement executed in the same block. I have not written manually. I have used something called "ipython" which stands for interactive python. And, no need to apologize for asking questions :)

Comment: I also have one more question i am trying to make a menu which calculate total price of one item including tax multiplied by number of item to be ordered. My code is : if choice == 2; Price = 6000;__PropTax = 0.20; tax = Price + __PropTax; Print tax. the only thing i can't understand is how can i code it in a way that the user is able to select number of item?

Comment: This is a bit unclear what you asking for. Please update the main question if this is related to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

object_of_type_product = Product(ProdName1, ProdNumber1, ProdPrice1, InvCount1)